# getting error with USPS package pickup API

Tags: php, usps

I was trying to integrate the USPS package pickup API and am getting the authorization error.

'80040b1a
    Authorization failure.  Perhaps username and/or password is incorrect.
    UspsCom::DoAuth'

Am using the same code from the USPS documentation.

https://www.usps.com/business/web-tools-apis/package-pickup.htm

The following is my full code.

```
<?php
    $url = "https://stg-secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPI.dll";
    $ch = curl_init();

    // set the target url
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);

    // parameters to post
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $data = 'API=CarrierPickupAvailability&XML=<CarrierPickupAvailabilityRequest USERID="013ODDPA7467" PASSWORD="XXXX" > 
        <FirmName>ABC Corp.</FirmName>
        <SuiteOrApt>Suite 777</SuiteOrApt>
        <Address2>1390 Market Street</Address2>
        <Urbanization></Urbanization>
        <City>Houston</City>
        <State>TX</State>
        <ZIP5>77058</ZIP5>
        <ZIP4>1234</ZIP4>
        </CarrierPickupAvailabilityRequest>';

    //send the POST values to USPS
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    $result=curl_exec ($ch);
    //return $result;
    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($result);
?>
```

Please help to resolve from this issue

Comment: I can't see PASSWORD in any of those examples. And it looks like they are doing GET and not POST in the examples

Comment: Password is not in the example. I tired with out the password, direct get method, stil getting the error. The userid is authorized by the USPS

Comment: When I paste https://secure.shippingapis.com/ShippingAPITest.dll?API=CarrierPickupAvailability&XML=%3CCarrierPickupAvailabilityRequest%20USERID=%22013ODDPA7467%22%3E%20%3CFirmName%3EABC%20Corp.%3C/FirmName%3E%20%3CSuiteOrApt%3ESuite%20777%3C/SuiteOrApt%3E%20%3CAddress2%3E1390%20Market%20Street%3C/Address2%3E%20%3CUrbanization%3E%3C/Urbanization%3E%20%3CCity%3EHouston%3C/City%3E%20%3CState%3ETX%3C/State%3E%20%3CZIP5%3E77058%3C/ZIP5%3E%20%3CZIP4%3E1234%3C/ZIP4%3E%20%3C/CarrierPickupAvailabilityRequest%3E in the web browser it say: "User 013ODDPA7467 is not authorized to use API CarrierPickup...

Comment: We have contact the USPS team, and they states that all the permissions to the particular userid is authorized.